# MongoDB shell authentication error

Tags: mongodb, database

I created a user and password for a database called **student**.:

> db.createUser({user:'Catalin',pwd:'Catalin',roles:[{role:'userAdmin',db:'student'}]});

So I restarted MongoDB Server with this command:

```
mongod --auth --dbpath C:\data\db
```

in another terminal, I connected to the sever with:

```
mongo
```

then queried the server with :

```
> db.getUsers()
[
    {
            "_id" : "student.Catalin",
            "user" : "Catalin",
            "db" : "student",
            "roles" : [
                    {
                            "role" : "userAdmin",
                            "db" : "student"
                    }
            ]
    }
```

]

went to the **student** database:

```
> use student
switched to db student
```

Entered my username and password succesfully via this command:

```
> db.auth('Catalin','Catalin');
1
```

and when I want to view my collections I get an error, WHY?:

```
> show collections
2016-03-07T15:54:41.166+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listCollections failed:
{
    "ok" : 0,
    **"errmsg" : "not authorized on student to execute command { listCollectio
ns: 1.0, filter: {} }",**
    "code" : 13
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
DB.prototype._getCollectionInfosCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:746:1
DB.prototype.getCollectionInfos@src/mongo/shell/db.js:758:15
DB.prototype.getCollectionNames@src/mongo/shell/db.js:769:12
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:695:9
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:594:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

**"errmsg" : "not authorized on student to execute command { listCollectio
    ns: 1.0, filter: {} }",**

P.S. : I'm using mongoDB 3.2

Answer (score 1):

The [userAdmin](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdmin) built-in role only provides the ability to create and modify roles and users on a database. If you need access to the database, you would need to either assign [database roles](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#database-user-roles), or other roles that has database access such as [dbOwner](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbOwner).

Please see [Built-in Roles](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#built-in-roles) for more detailed information.

You may also find these useful:

- [Manage users and roles](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/).
- [Enable client access control](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#enable-client-access-control).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 5 or befor DataBase MongoDB, pay attention to this point. You should not write anything in the mongod.conf file in the /etc/mongod.conf path. Use the following two commands to update the dependencies.

install dependencies :

sudo apt install libgconf-2-4

sudo add-apt-repository universe

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).